# How to solve impala insert with select query error?

Tags: sql, insert, cloudera, impala

i want to insert a row to service_log table with max+1 id value.

```
insert into bi_dev.service_logs values (select nvl(max(id),0) + 1 as count from bi_dev.service_logs , 1, now(), 0, "Error")
```

But this gives me the following error ;

```
AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 29:undefined: ..._dev.service_logs values (select nvl(max(id),0) + 1 as... ^ Encountered: SELECT Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: The select needs to be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: AnalysisException: Subqueries are not supported in the select list.
 :(((

Comment: `insert into bi_dev.service_logs select nvl(max(id),0) + 1, 1, now(), 0, "Error" from bi_dev.service_logs `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with most SQL dialects:

```
insert into bi_dev.service_logs 
select nvl(max(id),0) + 1 as count,
      , 1
      , now()
      , 0
      , "Error"
 from bi_dev.service_logs
```

Comment: bir şey değil ;-)